# jQuery UI Autcomplete: POST instead of GET

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

jQuery UI Autcomplete:

How can I POST the term to the search script instead of GET?

Comment: Wouldn't the POST be more appropriately used for obtaining the user's selection, rather than simply retrieving a list of choices?

Comment: @Robert - if receiving back JSON, a post might be better, esp. in ASP.NET MVC2 which (by default) refuses to serve up JSON for a GET request: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to supply a function as the [source](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source) for the plugin and have your function do the AJAX post to the server to get the matching data.

Comment: thanks, this is how it ended up working:
$("#search-cities").autocomplete(
{
  minLength: 2,
  source: function(request, response)
  {
      jQuery.post("http://redcupclassifieds.com/search_cities",
      {
          term: request.term
      },
      function(data)
      {
         response(data);
      }, "json");
    }
});

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify callback function for the source parameter. Here is an example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp