# Reading XML data from ASMX webservice for Jquery autocomplete

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, asmx

Me and ASMX web services do not get on. We argue. She brings up arguments we had in the past. It's a pain. Our relationship is on the rocks!

I have an ASMX web service, which I haven't serialised with the Newtonsoft library (as explained why here: http://encosia.com/2011/04/13/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/).  It looks like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string[] GetCitiesWithState(string isoalpha2, string prefixText)
    {
        var dict = AtomicCore.CityObject.GetCitiesInCountryWithStateAutocomplete(isoalpha2, prefixText);
        string[] cities = dict.Values.ToArray();
        return cities;
    }
```

Simple enough right? It return this when searching for `new`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <string>New Orleans, Louisiana</string>
  <string>New York, New York</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

I was expecting JSON, but after a bit of reading, it seems I shouldn't try and serialise the output - it should just happen right?  Anyway, so I have the following JQuery on the frontend:

```
$('#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>').autocomplete('<%=ResolveUrl("~/AtomicService/Assets.asmx/GetCitiesWithState")%>', {
            dataType: 'json',
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            parse: function (data) {
                var rows = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    rows[i] = { data: data.d[i], value: data.d[i].Value, result: data.d[i].Value };
                }
                return rows;
            },
            formatItem: function (row, i, n) {
                return row.Value;
            },
            extraParams: {
                minChars: 2,
                isoalpha2: '<%=Session["BusinessCountry"].ToString()%>',
                maxRows: 20,
                prefixText: function () {
                    return $('#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>').val()
                }
            },
            max: 20
        }).result(function (event, data, formatted) {
            if (data) {
                alert(data['Key']);
            }
        });
```

I can see the calls using Chrome:

[image: what one can see in Chrome]

And yet stuff all happens! There is no Jquery errors, no fireworks, no anything. She is ignoring me.

At first I was blaming the webservice, but I think this may have more to do with how I'm parsing and formatting the data in jquery.

So, **my question is**, what am I doing wrong and how can I make the autocomplete work correctly?

Help appreciated :)

EDIT: It may not be helpful, but this is what I see in Fiddler:

[image]

Comment: Which version of autocomplete plugin are you using? The plugin that got absorbed into jQueryUI is not suppored anymore (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)

Comment: You have dataType as JSON when the web service response is XML.

Comment: @Floyd Pink, I'm using the standard jquery ui one? @300 baud, I'll change it, see what that takes me... :)

Comment: @300 baud, I changed the dataType and contentType to XML; no luck :(

Comment: Also, in your fiddler screenshot you are calling your web service with a GET, but your jQuery code has `httpMethod: 'POST'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery UI autocomplete does not anymore use the formatItem method. That and many other such methods were present in autocomplete's earlier version that was a plugin [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete)

I have rewritten your code using the jQuery UI's autocomplete and it works for me with the below htm and asmx files.

Refer to the demos on the [jQueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) for more methods you could use.

I have used the json2.min.js from www.json.org
Also I have added the [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] attribute to the Service1 class so that it could directly be invoked from jQuery as a json web service.

These articles helped me:

[ASMX and JSON – Common mistakes and misconceptions](http://encosia.com/2010/03/03/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/)

[Using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

[3 mistakes to avoid when using jQuery with ASP.NET AJAX](http://encosia.com/2008/06/05/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/)

The htm file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>jQuery to ASMX</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/Scripts/json2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#txtInput").autocomplete({
            source:function (request, response) {
                var paramters = {
                    isoalpha2: '<%=Session["BusinessCountry"].ToString()%>',
                    prefixText: request.term
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Service1.asmx/GetCitiesWithState',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify(paramters),
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.each(data.d, function(index, value) {
                            return {
                                label: value,
                                value: index
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength:2,
            delay:500
        });

    });
</script>

<p>
    Hello, World!</p>
<label for="txtInput">
    Enter the string here:</label><input type="text" id="txtInput"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The asmx file

```
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace jQueryAutoCompleteBackEnd
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string[] GetCitiesWithState(string isoalpha2, string prefixText)
        {
            return new string[] { "New Orleans, Lousiana", "New York, New York" };
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 just for your effort in answering. I will see if this is the answer and come back. Thanks so much however :)

Comment: superb answer. This also lead me back to other areas I had used autocomplete and changed them to the newer version too.  Thanks very much :)

Comment: Thank you and dooburt for the question and solution, I found this very helpful. Although, I didn't include the `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` and that seems to have worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the asmx webmethod is returning XML rather than JSON is because the HTTP method is [GET rather than POST](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx).

In order for the autocomplete plugin to use POST you'll have to implement the source parameter using a callback function, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609047/jquery-ui-autcomplete-post-instead-of-get)