# Passing JSON objects from javascript to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Hi i have some complex types in javascript and want to pass them to my ASP.NET MVC app, the problem is how? I already added a custom ModelBinder (but i dont see why do i need to do that, unless i need to set some erros). The problem is i have;

```
var obj = 

    {
      "intvar":"222",
      "stringvar" :"31asd",
      "datevar":new Date(123),
      ....
    }
```

How do i pass this object to ASP.NET? via query string and via Post method.
EDIT: Soz for the bad explanation what i want is:

```
public class SomeObj
{
  public int intvar;
  public string stringvar;
  public DateTime datevar;
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
 public someActionMethod(SomeObj o)
{
}
```

}
Thkz in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make an AJAX call:

```
var json =
{
    intvar : 222,
    stringvar: '31asd',
    datevar: new Date(123)
}
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= Url.Action("handleJson", "<YOUR CONTROLLER NAME>") %>",
            dataType: "json",
            data: json,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

Then your controller method could accept parameters named the same as your json properties:

```
public ActionResult handleJson(int intvar, string stringvar, DateTime datevar)
{
    return Json("I did cool stuff but you can't see it :)");
}
```

Comment: I put the real question above sorry about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663905/reading-xml-data-from-asmx-webservice-for-jquery-autocomplete/5667674#5667674) answer helps. Look especially at all the attributes that the service class and service method has.

Also [this](http://encosia.com/2011/04/13/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/) article has some tips this question could use