# jqGrid - Toolbar search with auto complete from server - using json

Tags: search, jqgrid, autocomplete, jqgrid-asp.net

After reviewing these 2 questions and Oleg great answers

> [can jqgrid support dropdowns in the toolbar filter fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328072/can-jqgrid-support-dropdowns-in-the-toolbar-filter-fields/5329014#5329014)
>
> [jqGrid toolbar search with autocomplete using json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037104/jqgrid-toolbar-search-with-autocomplete-using-json-data)

I am trying to implement this feature with autocomplete of jQgrid toolbar search with json data coming form the server.

My code:

```
    myGrid.jqGrid({
    url: './WebService.asmx/ViewNQueryData',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
        if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    jsonReader: {
        root: function (obj) { return obj.d.rows; },
        page: function (obj) { return obj.d.page; },
        total: function (obj) { return obj.d.total; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.d.records; }
    },
    colModel: columnModel,
    colNames: columnNames,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 300],
    sortname: 'ID',
    sortorder: "asc",
    sortable: true,
    pager: "#ViewNQueryPager",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: 250,
    shrinkToFit: true,//If using frozen coulmns change to false.
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: ['ID'],
        //groupColumnShow: [false],
        //groupText: ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>'],
        groupSummary: [true],
        groupOrder: ['asc'],
        groupDataSorted: true,
        showSummaryOnHide: true
    },
    footerrow: true,
    userDataOnFooter: true,
    gridComplete: function () {
        $('#totalRecordsFound').html(myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') + " Customers");
    },
    loadError: function () {
        alert("Error fetching data");
    }
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#ViewNQueryPager',
                { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, view: true }, //option
                {}, // use default settings for edit
                {}, // use default settings for add
                {}, // delete instead that del:false we need this
                {multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, showQuery: true, onSearch: function (response) { showQueryDetails(); } },
                { height: 250, jqModal: false, closeOnEscape: true} // view options
                );

myGrid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'FirstName',
        {
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['cn'],
                dataInit: function (elem) {
                    $(elem).autocomplete({
                        source: './WebService.asmx/ViewNQueryData',
                        minLength: 1
                    });
                }
            }
        });

myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true });
```

But when i type in the search box the request doesnt get to my webService, and i get on exception in the browser, that he is trying to to this:

```
http://localhost:50949/WebService.asmx/ViewNQueryData?term=p
```

but :
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

My web service:

```
public JqGridData ViewNQueryData(int page, int rows, string sidx, string sord, bool _search, string filters)
{

    if (_search && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(filters))
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        jqGridSearchFilter searchFilter =
            serializer.Deserialize<jqGridSearchFilter>(filters);
        // use the searchFilter here
    }
    List<Person> allGridRows = JsonHelper.GetPersons();
    int recordsCount = allGridRows.Count;

    int startIndex = (page - 1) * rows;
    int endIndex = (startIndex + rows < recordsCount) ?
                   startIndex + rows : recordsCount;

    List<TableRow> gridRowsForResponse = new List<TableRow>(rows);
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        gridRowsForResponse.Add(new TableRow()
        {
            id = i,
            cell = new List<string>(3) {
                allGridRows[i].ID.ToString(),
                allGridRows[i].FirstName,
                allGridRows[i].LastName
        }
        });
    }

    return new JqGridData()
    {
        total = (recordsCount + rows - 1) / rows,
        page = page,
        records = recordsCount,
        rows = gridRowsForResponse
    };
}
```

What am i doing wrong? missing something? 
Also what do i need to return from the server? the regular JSON that the grid needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you use the same URL `'./WebService.asmx/ViewNQueryData'` for both jQuery UI Autocomplete and the the main grid `url`.

The main grid `url` should call web method having `(int page, int rows, string sidx, string sord, bool _search, string filters)` parameters and return the JSON data in the format

```
{
    "d": {
        "__type": "JqGridData",
        "total": 3,
        "page": 1,
        "records": 24,
        "rows": [
            {"id": 10, "cell": ["1", "Prabir", "Shrestha"]},
            {"id": 20, "cell": ["2", "Scott", "Gu"]},
            {"id": 43, "cell": ["4", "Bill", "Gates"]}
        ]
    }
}
```

On the other side the web method for the jQuery UI Autocomplete should has only one input parameter `term` and return back the data in the format like

```
["Bill", "Scott"]
```

or

```
[
    {
        "label": "Crab-Plover",
        "value": "Crab-Plover"
    },
    {
        "id": "Oenanthe isabellina",
        "label": "Isabelline Wheatear",
        "value": "Isabelline Wheatear"
    }
]
```

See "Datamodel" part of the jQuery UI Autocomplete [documentation](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137709/Autocomplete).

Because you use ASMX web services which wrap the returned JSON data in `d` property (`{d:{...}}`) you have to use some additional modifications to provide the data for jQuery UI Autocomplete in one of supported format. For example you can use `source` parameter of Autocomplete in callback form instead of the simple URL string. See [the answer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Use-Jquery-Autocomplete-a2e3e42e) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5667674/315935)) for example.